# Print second letter of each character in a list and replace letter

Tags: python, list, replace

So I have a list with names:

```
names = ['pete','carl','michael','steve']
```

Now I would like to only print the second letter of each name, so end up with( each letter underneath each other):

```
e
a
i
t
```

Also, I had a second question. I would like to replace a regular 'l' with a capital 'L' and print the names as (also each name underneath each other):

```
pete
carL
michaeL
steve
```

I hope someone knows how to do this :) Thank you in advance!

Comment: And what have you tried? Please see [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions. Furthermore, learn how to put together a solid [mcve] so your question is well received and easily answerable by the community.

Comment: `print([name[1] for name in names])`.

Comment: Shouldn't I refer to each name as 'name' then if I use that? How exactly should I do that? Or does the program understand 'for name in names' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple solution to your problem(s):

```
names = ['pete', 'carl', 'michael', 'steve']

def getSecondLetter(list):
    for string in list:
        if len(string) > 1:
            print(string[1])

def capitalizeLetterL(list):
    for string in list:
        print(string.replace("l", "L"))

capitalizeLetterL(names)
getSecondLetter(names)
```

Now, you can use it anywhere in the program, taking a list as a parameter.

---

#### Explanation

- I declared two [functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm), `capitalizeLetterL()` and `getSecondLetter()`, which helps us achieve the desired goal
- Inside `getSecondLetter()` I used a [for-in loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) to get each string from the list and return the second character, by subscripting it with `string[1]`, which returns the second character, because the indexes in a string start from `0`
- I used the [replace()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) function of string, to replace `l` with `L`

---

#### Edit

As per the OP's request, I've added a version which only uses while-loops:

```
names = ['pete', 'carl', 'michael', 'steve']

def getSecondLetter(list):
    i=0
    while i < len(list):
        string=list[i]
        if len(string) > 1:
            print(string[1])
        i+=1

def capitalizeLetterL(list):
    i = 0
    while i < len(list):
        string = list[i]
        print(string.replace("l", "L"))
        i+=1

capitalizeLetterL(names)
getSecondLetter(names)
```

Comment: Oh Thank you a lot, that might help me!
I was just wondering, do you also know if it is possible to answer these questions using a while statement? So a while loop?

Comment: @LB_99 I have edited the answer with the while-loop version! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use list comprehensions

```
names = ['pete','carl','michael','steve']

for n in names:
    if len(n) > 1:
        print n[1]


uppercaseLNames = [''.join([x.upper() if x == 'l' else x for x in n]) for n in names]

for n in uppercaseLNames:
    print n
```

Output

```
e
a
i
t
pete
carL
michaeL
steve
```

Answer (score 0):

> print (fruits)

```
['mango', 'apple', ' grapes']
```

> print (fruits[1][1])

```
p
```

Comment: this does not answer the question. The correct answer has already been accepted